# Proof of exponential property using Analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, analytic-continuation

The problem is to prove $e^{z+w} = e^z e^w$ for all $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$, **using analytic continuation.**

Can someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: I think that for "analytic continuation" the exercise is asking to prove this using the analytic definition of $e^z$, that is, you must use $$e^z:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!},\quad z\in\Bbb C$$ Anyway Im not completely sure :S

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, because we've previously done the proof using the method you're suggesting

Answer (score 0):

- Assume $w \in \mathbb{R}$

  Let $f(z) = e^{z+w}$ and $ g(z) = e^z e^w$ both entire (analytic on the whole complex plane, by the definition $e^z:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}$) .

  As you know $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) = g(x)$.

  It means that $f(z)-g(z)$ is an entire function with some non-isolated zeros on   the real line,

  hence it is identically zero and $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, f(z) = g(z)$.
- Repeat the same process with $w$

---

The analytic continuation works if we know that $f(z) = g(z)$ for $z \in U$ some open, for example the unit disk.

But the real line is not open in the complex topology, so it is not obvious how to use the analytic continuation.

Maybe you want to use some theorem about the complex logarithm for $|z-1 | < 1$ ?

Comment: Thank you, this really helps